# Router in AngularDart - OnActivate is called again on caller component when navigate to another path/component

Tags: angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I have a **list** component `OrganizationsComponent` and a **detail** component `OrganizationDetailComponent` (modal dialog) that using `route` to navigate.

When the navigation occur from **list** to **detail** [*OrganizationsComponent (list) >>> OrganizationDetailComponent (detail)*], the `onActivate` from **list** is called again (is the method from `OnActivate` interface).

I hoped that only `onActivate` on **detail** would be called, like is, *but not of the **list** again (caller)*.

If this is a normal behaviour, is there a way to stop the calling this method `onActivate` of the origin, in this case, on the list?

Environment:

- Dart SDK: 2.0.0-dev.43.0
- Angular: 5.0.0-alpha+8
- Angular_router: 2.0.0-alpha+8

Following the code:

**LIST CODE (partialy):**

-HTML

```
<div class="container-list">
    <material-fab raised (trigger)="goToDetail(null)">
        <material-icon icon="add"></material-icon>
    </material-fab>
    <br/>
    <material-list  class="shadow-box-material-list" elevation="2">
        <div *ngFor="let o of organizations">
          <material-list-item>
              <div>
                  <h4 class="material-list-item-content"><strong>{{o.name}}</strong></h4>
                  <p class="material-list-item-content">{{o.code}}</p>
              </div>
              <span class="row-spacer"></span>
              <div class="material-list-item-secondary">
                  <div>
                      <material-menu [menu]="menuModel" (click)="selectOrganization(o)">
                      </material-menu>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </material-list-item>
           <hr>
       </div>
    </material-list>
</div>
<router-outlet [routes]="rotas"></router-outlet>
```

-DART

```
class OrganizationsComponent implements OnActivate, OnDestroy {    
  final List<RouteDefinition> rotas = [
    new RouteDefinition(
        routePath: AppRotas.appLayoutHomeRoute,
        component: app_layout_home.AppLayoutHomeComponentNgFactory,
        useAsDefault: true
    ),
    new RouteDefinition(
        routePath: AppRotas.organizationDetailRoute,
        component: organization_detail.OrganizationDetailComponentNgFactory,
    ),
    new RouteDefinition(
      routePath: AppRotas.organizationDetailAddRoute,
      component: organization_detail.OrganizationDetailComponentNgFactory,
    ),
  ];

  final Router _router;
  List<Organization> _organizations;

  OrganizationsComponent(this._router);

  // ** HERE IS CALLED AGAIN WHEN NAVEGATES TO DETAIL (calling goToDetail() method) **
  @override
  onActivate(routeStatePrevious, routeStateCurrent) async {   
    _organizations = await _organizationService.getOrganizations();   
  }

  @override
  ngOnDestroy() async {
    _appLayoutService.searchEnabled = false;   
  }

  void goToDetail(Organization organization) {
    if (organization == null) {
      _router.navigate(AppRotas.organizationDetailAddRoute.toUrl());
    } else {
      _router.navigate(AppRotas.organizationDetailRoute.toUrl(parameters: {
        AppRotas.organizationUuidParameter: organization != null ? organization.id : null
      }));
    }
  }

  List<Organization> get organizations {
    return _organizations;
  }
  // ...
}
```

**DETAIL CODE (partialy):**

-HTML

```
<modal [visible]="true">
    <material-dialog headered class="headered-dialog">
        <div header>
            <h3>{{labelOrganization}}</h3>
        </div>
        <material-content>
            <material-input class="width-300" [(ngModel)]="organization.name" floatingLabel [label]="labelName" required [requiredErrorMsg]="msgValorRequerido"></material-input>
            <material-input [(ngModel)]="organization.code" floatingLabel [label]="labelCode"></material-input>
        </material-content>
        <div footer>
            <material-button  (trigger)="saveOrganization()">{{buttonLabelSave}}
                <material-icon icon="save"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <material-button autoFocus (trigger)="goBack()">{{buttonLabelBack}}
                <material-icon icon="arrow_back"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
        </div>
    </material-dialog>
</modal>
```

-DART

```
class OrganizationDetailComponent implements OnActivate {

  final Location _location;

  Organization organization = new Organization();

  OrganizationDetailComponent( this._location);

  @override
  Future onActivate(routeStatePrevious, routeStateCurrent) async {
    if (routeStateCurrent.parameters.isNotEmpty) {
      var uuid = routeStateCurrent.parameters[AppRotas.organizationUuidParameter];
      if (uuid != null && uuid.isNotEmpty) {
        organization = await _organizationService.getOrganizationById(uuid);
      }
    }
  }

  void goBack() {
    _location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Angular 5.0.0-alpha+8 and Angular_router 2.0.0-alpha+8.

Comment: This seems to be working as intended. onActivate is called on every component in the chain of routes from root to leaf upon activation. In fact, because `OrganizationsComponent` isn't reusable, it will be destroyed and recreated when navigating between its child routes.

Comment: Right, this makes sense now! But about reuse, I tried to implement the `Future<bool> canReuse(RouterState current, RouterState next)` from `CanReuse` interface on `OrganizationsComponent`, but it is not called. It works on `angular_router 2.0.0-alpha+8`?

Comment: I saw the discussion [dart-lang/angular](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1127) about CanReuse. A bit werid how to use, because needs to define CanReuse since from the root. But I got it now.

Comment: Hi @Muka, I am running into the same issues, about 2 years later... do you mind to explain exactly how did you solve this issue where your list kept being populated each time you went to the details page and back?

Comment: @ito, I implemented on parent something similar to `void onActivate(RouterState routerStatePrevious, RouterState routerStateCurrent) async { if (routerStatePrevious.routePath.path == routerStateCurrent.routePath.parent.path) return; }`. If previous path equals current parent path, doesn't need to call this again.